# How to change key mapping in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to change some shortcuts for speed settings in my processes. I know that there is an option to change it from *Tools > Editor Options > Key Mappings* menu but I want to re-assign some keys manually.

Is it possible to assign them from Delphi IDE directly without using any third party?

Comment: Yes, you can remap keys, but only using a custom (partial) keybinding package, which you can easily write and install yourself. [An example can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/rvelthuis/INSlessKeyBindings). You cannot, however, directly change key mappings "on the fly", unless you use a third party tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting @Rudy Velthuis' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032286/how-to-change-key-mapping-in-delphi-10-1-berlin#comment85070571_49032286) as a answer:

> Yes, you can remap keys, but only using a custom (partial) keybinding package, which you can easily write and install yourself. An [example](https://github.com/rvelthuis/INSlessKeyBindings) can be found on GitHub. You cannot, however, directly change key mappings "on the fly", unless you use a third party tool.