# Delphi IDE Shortcuts modification

Tags: delphi

Is there a possibility to modify default shortcut in Delphi Borland IDE?

I would like to change Ctrl + Y from "Delete Current line" to "Redo".

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49032286/4820670 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration option for it, but you could write a Keymapping Enhancement module for it. I doubt that it is worth the effort though.

Comment: Exactly what is said in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49032286/4820670...